# elmah doesn't redirect to custom error page when error comes from child action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, elmah, custom-error-pages

Whenever an exception is thrown from my normal controller action methods elmah correctly redirects the browser to the custom error page.

However, I have an Html.RenderAction call in my master page that can calls my HomeController.TopLevelNav method.  The TopLevelNav method is a child action, and if it throws an exception elmah doesn't redirect the user to the error page.  Instead I see the ysod "runtime error" page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to cite Scott Wilson from the ELMAH Google groups:

> --- soccerdad  wrote:
>
> > My question is what's the "best practice" means to accomplish what I 
> >     described. Should I handle Application_Error in global.asax and do 
> >     those things? Are other folks doing something different?
>
> The best practice would be to use Elmah as-is and to configure a
>   custom  error page in the web.config file.  Elmah will catch errors
>   and log them without any interference on the rest  of the application.
>   If you want a custom error page, that can easily be  set up in the
>   standard ASP.NET web.config CustomErrors section. Neither  will affect
>   the operation of the other.  Regards,  Scott